# RecyclerView+PageSnapHelper onConfigurationChanged Layout Incorrect

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Such as the title.
I use recyclerview+pagesnaphelper to play video(like viewpager).

After onConfigurationChanged for LANDSCAPE,the screen not show the current page completely, the screen show part current page and next page.

What's the possible reason for the question?

Comment: Are using fixed height or width of viewpager item?

Comment: Both are match_parent.

Comment: Swipe down to the next page and then full screen is corret.but,swipe up and full screen is incorret.